Screenshot of the Week #116 - Going fast!

This contest is over.
previous contest | next contest
Hello and welcome to the 116th edition of the Screenshot of the Week!
To start with, congratulations to the winner of the previous contest! Pinckerman's screenshot from no-mans-sky won with 12 upvotes!


To submit a screenshot, simply post it as an answer to this question, but please take note of the following:

One screenshot per post, and one post per person, please!
Limited picture modifications are allowed, such as cropping, simple filters, and blurring of identifying info such as names, but not adding other images or text.
To ensure a fair playing field, please post screenshots you've taken yourself rather than ones you found online.
Stack Exchange’s Code of Conduct still applies - so if it would be unacceptable to post normally, it’s unacceptable here.

Also, try to avoid pictures that include spoilers. We want everyone to be able to enjoy this contest, so the less spoilers the better.
How long will the contest run?
We will accept submissions for a week, until 19:00 UTC of 2024-05-27, then have a second week-long period where only voting will be accepted. This is to give every submission, even those posted at the end of the first week, a chance to be voted on by everyone.
After the end of the second week, at 19:00 UTC of 2024-06-03, we will count upvotes only to determine the winning screenshot, which will be featured for a week on the main site's photo widget.

Going Fast!
Show us screenshots of really fast things!
As a reminder, we're always accepting suggestions for themed weeks, and have compiled that suggestion process into a question of its own.  Additionally, there is the hall of fame you can check out that contains all the previous contest winners.

Not gonna lie, congratulating myself was awkward

Does it need to be something fast, or can it also depict a situation of someone trying to run away fast? I'm fine if the answer is no for the 2nd part.

@Clockwork just post it and we'll see, but I'm ok with that

@Clockwork I consider most themes open to interpretation. So long as there's at least some sort of reason to link it to the theme it should be fine :)

@pinckerman Wipqozn has before, and as a mod its ever more awkward.  (click the Wipqozn's submission link for an easter egg in that post)

@TimmyJim LOL how did I miss that? That's exactly the feeling, yep

"Everybody's Super Sonic racing, try to keep your feet right on the ground..."

For an unknown reason the markdown code for tags isn't rendered as intended, reletated Meta post.

It looks like both answers lost a score (the hedgehog one was at 5 and dropped down to 4). I wonder if it's because someone who voted, deleted their gaming stack exchange account.

@Clockwork no, they both received a downvote, which will be ignored by the way

My favorite hedgehog in shadow-the-hedgehog


Ow the Edge

@Robotnik What a very appropriate nickname too

Holy crap, it's a dragon!

elden-ring
Context:

 I was still at the early part of the game, having fun discovering Elden Ring, playing it along with my fiancée, without knowing exactly what to expect. At some point, I saw a bonfire with a few guys standing around, on a tiny patch of island, so I decided to approach to find out who they were. Then all of a sudden, the dragon came crashing into the bonfire, killing everyone, before proceeding to charge toward me, so I started running away as fast as I could. I couldn't believe there's dragons in this game.


"Gotta go fast!"
...wait, wrong game.
Meat boy from super-meat-boy


What is the context of the screenshot? It looks funny though

@Clockwork have you ever played it? It's a fast pace game, and in this world you often have sawblades chasing you, so you have to run to survive

Nah, never played it. I only heard a bit about it. I suspected it had something to do with the gameplay
